# Python Getting job game

Tags: python

I am currently working on a Python game influenced by DankMemer Bot on Discord! I am having trouble with getting jobs in the game. The job list is

```
au = 'Author'
de = 'Designer'
pr = 'Programmer'
do = 'Doctor'
job_list = [au, de, pr, do]
```

I made a getting job function so the way if the player typed !gj (short for getting a job) in the text game.

```
elif chat == '!gj':
    player_job = player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level)
    print(player_job)
```

I did

```
print(player_job)
```

To check if the command was running ok. The

```
player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level)
```

Function is defined as

```
def player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level):
    print('Available jobs :')
    for i,job in enumerate(job_list, 1):
        print(i, job)
    job_chose = input('What job number do you want? ("q" to exit)\n')
    if job_chose == 'q':
        return player_job
    try:
        job_chose = int(job_chose)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please use the number next to the job')
        return player_job

    if job_chose <= len(job_list):
        if player_job == None:
            player_job = job

            return player_job
        else:
            print('You already have a job!')
            retire = input('Would you like to retire from your current job?  y/n\n')
            if retire == 'y':
                player_job = None
                player_job = job
                return player_job
            elif retire == 'n':
                print('Sorry you can only have 1 job at a time!')
                return player_job
            else:
                print('y or n please!')
                return player_job
    else:
        print('Please use the number next to the job')
        return player_job
```

But when I run the function it works perfectly fine
[image]

until I type the number that is next to the job.
[image]

If I typed 1, it should print

```
Author
```

But No matter what I put in, It just says the doctor. Why does it do that?

The full code is below

```
import random
import sys
import time

player_total_work = 0
player_earn_work = 0
player_work_exp = 0
player_work_max = 100
player_job = None
au = 'Author'
de = 'Designer'
pr = 'Programmer'
do = 'Doctor'
job_list = [au, de, pr, do]

player_level = 1

command_list_ = ['!gj [Get a job]','!w [work]', '!f [fish (if you have a fishing rod in your inventory)]', '!h [hunt (if you have a hunting rifle in your inventory)]', '!bj [blackjack (gamble)]', '!sl [slots (gamble)]', '!ro [roll (gamble)]', '!sh [the shop]', '!cy [Company]', '!inv [inventory]', '!bal [currency]', '!profile [stats, money, name.. etc]', ]

def command_list(command_list_):
    for i,command in enumerate(command_list_, 1):
        print(i, command)

def player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level):
    print('Available jobs :')
    for i,job in enumerate(job_list, 1):
        print(i, job)
    job_chose = input('What job number do you want? ("q" to exit)\n')
    if job_chose == 'q':
        return player_job
    try:
        job_chose = int(job_chose)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please use the number next to the job')
        return player_job

    if job_chose <= len(job_list):
        if player_job == None:
            player_job = job

            return player_job
        else:
            print('You already have a job!')
            retire = input('Would you like to retire from your current job?  y/n\n')
            if retire == 'y':
                player_job = None
                player_job = job
                return player_job
            elif retire == 'n':
                print('Sorry you can only have 1 job at a time!')
                return player_job
            else:
                print('y or n please!')
                return player_job
    else:
        print('Please use the number next to the job')
        return player_job

def game(player_job):
    while True:
        chat = input('!c for commands list\n')
        if chat == '!c':
            command_list(command_list_)
            
        elif chat == '!gj':
            player_job = player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level)
            print(player_job)

        else:
            pass

game(player_job)
```

Comment: Hint: you have to use `job_chose` and `job_list` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet:

```
if job_chose <= len(job_list):
        if player_job == None:
            player_job = job
```

What do you expect `job` to be when the flow of execution reaches `player_job = job`? What was the last value stored in `job` before you reached this line?

Comment: Oh wait, the last thing that job is is 'Doctor' so it would print as doctor but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: @danksoirst Right, so, instead of getting the selected job from `job`, you will have to pull it from `job_list`. Use the player's input as an index. Keep in mind that indices start at zero, rather than one (I'm mentioning this since your jobs are numbered 1 through 4, and the user would enter `1` for the first job and not `0`, for example).